# Replacing Nested Double Quotes in a String

Tags: php, regex, typography

So I am a typography-nazi (they are like grammar-nazis on steroids), and I have a string, which might contain **multiple level double quotes**, such as:

```
$str = 'Outer text "first level "second level "third level" second level" first level" outer text';
```

In my native language, a maximum of three level quoting is typographically correct, with each level having its own quotation mark. I would like to **replace** all the double quote *pairs* to their corresponding entities, such that:

- 1st level: „text” (`&bdquo;` and `&rdquo;`)
- 2nd level: »text« (`&raquo;` and `&laquo;`)
- 3rd level: ’text’ (`&rsquo;`)
- any additional levels: ’text’ (`&rsquo;`)

So the above text will output as:

> Outer text „first level »second level ’third level’ second level« first level” outer text

Also, it is possible that there are sibling `""` pairs in the string:

```
$str = 'Quote from my book: "She didn\'t feel "depressed", "tired" or "sad"."';
```

So this will output as:

> Quote from my book: „She didn't feel »depressed«, »tired« or »sad«.”

(This could be tricky, but we know that a `"` always followed or preceeded by a space , or punctuation `,`, `.`, `;`, `?`, `!`)

Finally, the `$str` may contain HTML as well, where the attributes' quotation marks shouldn't be changed:

```
$str = '<p class="quote">The error said: <span class="error_msg">"Please restart your "fancy" computer!"</span></p>';
```

I've heard that using *recursive regexp* would be a possible solution but I'm searching for a more **efficient way** because the strings might be long HTML texts.

***UPDATE:*** It seems I slipped across CSS's `quotes` property and the `<q>` element. This makes inline quotes much more elegant.

Comment: I can't actually think of any magical or simple function to do so. Don't be afraid of regex dude, it's on average 300% slower than the simple string replace function, but to really notice it you would need to run it agains HUGE texts....

Comment: offtop: Why you using 'right-pointing double angle quotation mark' on the left and '&laquo;' on the right?

Comment: @sectus: In Hungarian typography, this is the correct symbol to use when quoting within a quote: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks#Hungarian

Comment: I don't think the two type of your input can be distinguished from each other, so for example: `"b" m "c"` can be `„b” m „c”` or can be `„b» m «c”` too. Is white-space alone enough to tell if a `"` is an ending mark or not (i'm thinking something like `/\w"/` is an end marker, `/\s"/` is a start marker)?

Answer (score 1):

try this `"#\"(([^()]+|(?R))*)\"#"` is regex  recursive

sample

```
class Replace1{
   public $Out,$Depth=0;
   function __construct($Query){
        $this->Depth=0;
        $this->Out=$this->Reaplce($Query);  
   }
   function Reaplce($Query){
      //echo "**********".$Query.$this->Depth."\n";
       $Query = preg_replace_callback("#\"(([^()]+|(?R))*)\"#",function($m){
             $this->Depth++;
             $R=$this->Reaplce($m[1]);
             $this->Depth--;
            return $R;
        },$Query);  
        switch($this->Depth){
          case 0:
             return $Query;
          case 1:
             return '&bdquo;'.$Query.'&rdquo;';
          case 2:
             return '&raquo;'.$Query.'&laquo;'; 
          case 3:
             return '&rsquo;'.$Query.'&rsquo;';  
          default:
             return '&rsquo;'.$Query.'&rsquo;';                     
        }
        return $Query;

  }


}
$obj=new Replace1('Outer text "first level "second level "third level" second level" first level" outer text');
echo $obj->Out;
```

old php

```
function R($m){
        Replace1::$Depth++;
        $R=Replace1::Reaplce($m[1]);
        Replace1::$Depth--;
        //echo "***".$R.$this->Depth."\n";
        return $R;
}
class Replace1{
public static $Out,$Depth=0;

    function __construct($Query){
    self::$Depth=0;
    self::$Out=self::Reaplce($Query);   
}

static function Reaplce($Query){
    //echo "**********".$Query.$this->Depth."\n";

    $Query = preg_replace_callback("#\"(([^()]+|(?R))*)\"#","R",$Query);
    //echo "**********".$Query.$this->Depth."\n";   
    switch(self::$Depth){
        case 0:
           return $Query;
        case 1:
           return '&bdquo;'.$Query.'&rdquo;';
        case 2:
           return '&raquo;'.$Query.'&laquo;'; 
        case 3:
           return '&rsquo;'.$Query.'&rsquo;';  
        default:
           return '&rsquo;'.$Query.'&rsquo;';         


    }
    return $Query;

}


}
$obj=new Replace1('Outer text "first level "second level "third level" second level" first level" outer text');
echo Replace1::$Out;
```

output is

```
Outer text „first level »second level ’third level’ second level« first level” outer text
```

html view

```
Outer text &bdquo;first level &raquo;second level &rsquo;third level&rsquo; second level&laquo; first level&rdquo; outer text
```

if remove echo comment `//` the output will be

```
 **********Outer text "first level "second level "third level" second level" first level" outer text0
 **********first level "second level "third level" second level" first level1
 **********second level "third level" second level2
 **********third level3
 Outer text &bdquo;first level &raquo;second level &rsquo;third level&rsquo; second level&laquo; first level&rdquo; outer text
```

Comment: it throws an error: E_ERROR : type 1 -- Using $this when not in object context -- at line 11 http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v0p-xsq

Comment: your php version is older than 5.3.3. no problem i put code for old php too

Comment: yah it's working now :) only for the first type of strings though!

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML to do this kind of smart-quoting is, if not impossible, a really tricky task.

I have build [JoliTypo](https://github.com/jolicode/JoliTypo), which use a DOM loader (`\DomDocument`), and process all text strings to apply some typography fix on it: EnglishQuotes is one of them but it only handle first level at the moment. In French we also have different quotes hierarchy so it's definitely in my todo list.

While @mohammad solution works for simple string, coupled to JoliTypo you may have a chance to get what you want in a reliable way for large HTML docs.

Can I ask in which locale this kind of quoting (`Outer text „first level »second level ’third level’ second level« first level” outer text`) is used?

Comment: The quoting rules are for [Hungarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks#Hungarian).